# Generate square image from portrait thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, image

I have portrait images with about 200x600 size. I would like to create a square version of it with 600x600 size. 
Is it possible somehow?

Unfortunately the hard crop set the width first and I get only the center of the image.

add_image_size( 'square', 600, 600, true ); 
Required below. Upload portrait and get square version of it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I recently found this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/square-thumbnails which seems to do exactly what you need.

It will create a square thumbnail image and fit the original image inside the square.

I haven't tested it on a production site, so I can vouch for the plugin, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but looks good. I had only 40-50 products, so I recropped them in Photoshop :/

Answer (score 1):

WordPress functions for image manipulation can't work like this, they can crop images, but they can't fill them up to be expanded.

Images can have different backgrounds, and automatically choosing colours for that is not easy to do. If the images are with background transparency, then, it is easier to do, but still, WordPress can't do that. I am not sure of any plugin for WordPress that can do this.

Best way to do this is to hire someone to code it for you, and again, it will work fine only if images don't have background.